# Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance (Firestore)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I received the following error on using `Firestore`'s setData operation:

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber hasPrefix:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000003'"

Is this because I am sending to `Firestore` custom objects? I had checked `Firestore`'s dashboard to see if I could add fields adhering to these custom objects (i.e. of type [Int: Timestamp]), and saw that I could...

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Below is my code call (customObjectOne is of type [String: Date] and customObjectTwo is of type [Int: Date]):

```
db.collection("collection").document("document").setData([
                "y": customObjectOne,
                "z": customeObjectTwo,
                ], options: SetOptions.merge())
```

Comment: Could be the custom objects. Tell us what `customObjectOne` & `customeObjectTwo` are

Comment: @staticVoidMan `customObjectOne` is of type [String: Date] and `customObjectTwo` is of type [Int: Date]

Comment: Hm... I wonder if a `Date` object can be sent across as-is.

Comment: hasPrefix is a string method. NSNumber is not a string. Someone is sending a string method to an NSNumber. Looks like customObjectTwo with its key of type Int is something Firebase doesn't like. "I wonder..." => read the documentation.

Comment: @Chris Share the documentation link regarding these "custom" objects.

Comment: @gnasher729 changing the int key to string solved it for me, i guess firestore restricts objects to string key values.

Comment: You should write up what you did as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve per @gnasher720 ...

Firestore does not accept write operations where objects sent have non-string keys (i.e. [Int: Date]).

Changing my previously integer key to string type resolved my issue.